# Docker invalid reference format?

Tags: docker

I try use this docker command

```
docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 \
-v \host_mntC\eosio\work:/work 
-v \host_mntC\eosio\data:/mnt/dev/data \
-v \host_mntC\eosio\config:/mnt/dev/config \ 
   \host_mntC\eosio\contracts:/contracts   eosio/test  /bin/bash \ 
-c "nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin \
-d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config \
--http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* \
--contracts-console --http-validate-host=false"
```

I need the files to be saved locally, when I start EOSIO. What I'm doing is wrong, thank you. System Windows 10.

Comment: consider splitting the command over multiple lines so it's easier for people to help you because it's easier to read. Also please explain what you want to happen

Answer (score 2):

It's just a missing `-v` before `\host_mntC\eosio\contracts:/contracts`.